# how to estimate parameters in a mixture of two different distributions using R or any other programming language?

Tags: java, c, r, statistics

I have to estimate the parameters of a mixture distribution which consists of Pareto distribution and Exponential distribution. I am using the maximum likelihood estimation procedure by using log-likelihood function and differentiating it with respect to each parameter. Since the log-likelihood equation is nonlinear, I have to use Newton Rhapson's iterative method. How can I do this using `R` or any other programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [flexmix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/index.html)-package

Answer (score 0):

[ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) has [fitting facilities](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TGraph.html#TGraph:Fit) that make this relatively easy.

Comment: Sure does but not that the question was not tagged C++.

Comment: I believe C++ falls into the set of "any other programming language" but outside of the set of "languages which were tagged"

Comment: @Dirk: Sure---but as JD says---I took the "other" languages bit as license to stray. However, it *is* worth mentioning that people who find R natural and comfortable may find ROOT unnatural and uncomfortable: the tools are specialized for different domains. Certainly, I won't be hurt if laks takes a different approach here...